# dual boot - correct procedure to resize paritions with ubuntu 18.10 and windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, windows-10, 18.10

I have a dual boot set up with ubuntu 18.10 and windows 10. [This is my partition scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw8F9.png)

I want to reduce the Ubuntu partition by 10GB and add them to Windows. I have backed my data up for both systems. My plan is to boot into ubuntu live from an external usb and use `gparted` to reduce the ubuntu partition. How can I then transfer that unallocated space to windows? I imagine the unallocated space will be to the right of the ubuntu partition, can I just drag it to its left and then expand the windows partition? Are there any extra steps I should take to avoid data loss?

Comment: The extra step you need is backup all data. Also, no, you can't just drag unallocated space from right to left. Usually, you'd move the whole partition to the right, but in your case, /dev/sda4 is too full, so there is no easy way to repartition.

Comment: How much space (more or less) would I need to free to reparation easily (and safely)? I have many files backed up on several hard drives so I guess I could just temporarily delete them from the laptop and restore them after having repartitioned

Comment: No, issue is either drive is too small or you have too much data on drive. If you houseclean do not restore. Windows needs 30% free to run well, at 10% free a defrag takes forever. And Ubuntu needs free space also to work well, but can get by with a bit less than Windows, but not much less than you now have.

Comment: I totally agree with @oldfred

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to install ubuntu to an extra external HD. Each OS will have more space and unless you do heavy read/writes, not much slowness.